# Program that count prime factorazation of numbers

Tags: c, counter, primes, prime-factoring, factor-analysis

I want to make a program that finds prime factorization of numbers with counter instead of `scanf`. I have implemented some code but I don't get the results I want!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000

int main()
{
    int num;
    int counter;
    int factor = 2;

    for (counter = 2; counter <= MAX; counter++) {
        printf("factorazation of number %d is", counter);

        while (factor<counter) {
            int power = 0;
            if (counter%factor == 0) {

                //  int power=0;
                while (counter%factor == 0) {
                    counter = counter / factor;
                    power++;
                }
                printf("%d^%d\n", factor, power);
                if (counter != 1)
                    printf("X");


            }
            factor++;
        }

        if (counter != 1)
            printf("%d^1.\n", factor);

        //  printf("factorazation of number %d is",counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: What results do you want! And why did you end your sentence with a `!`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two bugs.

1) You need to set `factor` back to 2 inside the for-loop

2) You can't use `counter` to get the next number when you also modify `counter` in the loop. You need to use two variables.

Like:

```
int current;   
for (current= 2; current<= MAX; current++) {
    factor = 2;         // set factor back to 2
    counter = current;  // make a copy of current into counter
                        // so that it's okay to modify counter inside the loop
    printf("factorazation of number %d is", counter);
```

Besides that you need to fix the use of `\n` to get a nice print.

Comment: Thank you very much that was my problem